# Get product inventory before and after saving

Tags: product, inventory

I want to log each time someone changes the qty of in stock products in magento. I hooked into the catalog_product_prepare_save event, but can't seem to figure out how to access the values after save (for the inventory).
Currently in my controller I have:

```
public function logProductSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    //info about logged in admin user
    Mage::log("reached logProductSave");
    $userArray = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getData();
    $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();
    $userEmail = $user->getUser()->getEmail();
    $userFirstname = $user->getUser()->getFirstname();
    $userLastname = $user->getUser()->getLastname();
    $userUsername = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
    $userPassword = $user->getUser()->getPassword();
    //Product changes
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    if ($product->hasDataChanges()) 
    {
    $newValues = array_diff($product->getData(), $product->getOrigData());
    $oldValues = array_diff($product->getOrigData(), $product->getData());
    $added = array_diff_key($product->getData(), $product->getOrigData());
    $unset = array_diff_key($product->getOrigData(), $product->getData());

    //before save qty
    $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();

    //after save qty

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `catalog_product_prepare_save` is the best event for this.
The event is dispatched before saving the product and if there are errors in the save process your values won't be changed but you will still log a qty change.
You should use `catalog_product_save_commit_after`. This is dispatched after the product has been saved in the database.
You should observe this event only for the admin. So add this in the `config.xml`  for your module.

```
<adminhtml><!-- instead of global -->
    <events>
        <!-- your event here -->
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

You can get the original stock item like this:

```
$origStockData = $product->getOrigData('stock_item')->getOrigData();
```

And you can compare it with the new data

```
$stockData = $product->getStockItem()->getData();
```